# Loot missing from console versions of skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, version-differences

I know most loot is random, but some is also static, especially loot that is in world and not in a chest or on a corpse.  Last year I played Skyrim twice on my PC and now I've been playing it on my PS3.  It seems like on the PC version I have found items like `boots of strength` **both times** early in the game.  I noticed I didn't find them playing the PS3 but wrote it off as having overlooked them.

I also seem to remember finding [Ebony Gauntlets of Extreme Archery](http://www.skyrimwiki.com/Ebony_Gauntlets_of_Extreme_Archery) during the [Red Eagle](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Eagle) quest laying next to the treasure chest behind Red Eagle's coffin **both times** on the PC.  I just finished that quest on the PS3 specifically for those gauntlets because I'm trying a stealth/ranger toon, but guess what, no gauntlets.  Now I'm beginning to wonder if I overlooked the boots earlier or if they're just not as abundant or missing all together in the console game.

Am I remembering wrong? Are they random and I got lucky twice before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed stuff going missing between savegames. In the one game there is a book on the desk. I died an loaded. No book. Don't know what was up. But it was strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dungeons#Loot), skyrim can generate loot that is level-dependent (and random?), even in the open.

> Level-dependent items include: ...
>
> Some items sitting out in the open. Unlike previous Elder
>   Scrolls games, in Skyrim developers can place dummy objects, for
>   example on tables or shelves. These dummy objects are then replaced by
>   a leveled item when the dungeon contents are spawned. This is most
>   frequently done with potions, but is also done for armor, arrows,
>   books, soul gems, and weapons.

Comment: This answer would be better if it quoted from or summarized the salient points from the page you've linked to.